# Projection of Collections in lucene query in hibernate search

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, hibernate-search

I am trying to use @IndexEmbedded annotation for indexing. The results are correct when i check using Luke.( i am getting all the elements of List).

But when i tried to use this list in projection in Lucene Query, i am getting null.

I read somewhere that 
"projection does not work on collections or maps which are indexed via @IndexedEmbedded"

Is there any other way out to project this List.

```
  @Indexed
public class Item {

   ...

  @IndexedEmbedded
  private List<Keyword> keywords;

   ...
}

@Indexed
public class Keyword {

   ...

  @Field
  private String value;

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Right, as per documentation:

```
you can only project simple properties of the indexed entity or its embedded associations. This means you cannot project a whole embedded entity.

projection does not work on collections or maps which are indexed via @IndexedEmbedded
```

One could try to implement a custom two-way field bridge for keywords by encoding the order and content of the actual keywords in the document. Not sure whether it is a good idea though.

Comment: Ok, I agree what you said. But I just discovered that while projecting if I specify FullText.DOCUMENT as a paramter, it returns the document row from the lucene index.

Can i use this document to compose objects?? Will it affect the performance?

Comment: Sure, you can get the whole Lucene Document and take it from there